# How to solve indexer status "suspended" (n in backlog)

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, indexing

One of the indexers that are configured to be updated on schedule is locked in the state "suspended" and does not get updated anymore.

Output of `bin/magento indexer:status`

```
+----------------------------+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------+---------------------+
| Title                      | Status           | Update On | Schedule Status               | Schedule Updated    |
+----------------------------+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------+---------------------+
| ...                        |                  |           |                               |                     |
| IntegerNet_Solr            | Reindex required | Schedule  | suspended (101028 in backlog) | 2018-09-24 15:28:44 |
| ...                        |                  |           |                               |                     |
+----------------------------+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Others show `idle (0 in backlog)` and the current time in the "Schedule Updated" column, so the indexer schedule is generally working.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 18):

I found out, that the status is set in `\Magento\Framework\Mview\View::suspend()` and removed in `\Magento\Framework\Mview\View::resume()`.

These methods are only called in `\Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer::reindexAll()` to suspend the scheduled indexing before a forced full reindexing and to resume it afterwards or if an exception occurs.

But if the process is terminated without exception, e.g. killed, segfaulted or even runs into a non-recoverable fatal error, the status stays "suspended" and there are no means to resume it.

**Solution:** make sure, there really is no full reindex running, then update the status via SQL.

You'll find all the statuses with:

```
select * from mview_state;
```

and update it like this:

```
update mview_state set status='idle' where view_id='integernet_solr';
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a full proof solution?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to edit database to do so, you can do the same by resetting and indexers and then reindexing them again by using following commands;

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

---

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but it only resets the status (i.e. "in progress"), not the mview state

Comment: I'm not sure if triggering a full reindex again would have worked, but even if so, I'd like to avoid it

Comment: I had the same problem in my case where the process was suspended , above worked for me then. It was magento 2.1.x though.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to experiment a bit to find out more :)

Comment: What was the outcome of your experiment?

Comment: i found that the reset, php bin/magento indexer:reset, did not change the suspended flag, but did make it so i could reindex properly and that in turn changed the flag back to idle. i suggest using the: php bin/magento indexer:reset suggested above.

Comment: This is the first answer that shows up and blatantly incorrect. It would be helpful if you deleted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation (Magento 2.4.0), calling to indexer (either `bin/magento indexer:reset` or `bin/magento indexer:reindex`) doesn't get the backlog number of Product Categories and Catalog Product Rule down.

After paying some investigation, I found that my cronjob wasn't run successfully. Calling it would significantly reduce these numbers.
You'll want to give it a try:

- `bin/magento cron:run`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounders a "stuck" indexer (probably after a failed import or something like that), a `_cl` tables clear may be wise.

This article explains the process by clearing the `_cl` table:

https://www.vannoortproductions.nl/magento-2-indexer-stuck-at-processing/

after that you may:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cron:run
```

Monitor the above processes for errors an get a DB backup before.